# Loading Adsense from a file into iframe

Tags: iframe, adsense

I've created a completely AJAX-based website so in order for me to have Adsense display relevant content, I've created an adsense.html with site-relevant keywords in it.
However the ads don't seem to be picking up the key words.

Does this adsense html file make sense?:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
   google_ad_client = "ca-pub-123456789";
   google_ad_slot = "123456789";
   google_ad_width = 200;
   google_ad_height = 200;
   //-->
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
   </script>
KEYWORD,KEYWORD,KEYWORD.
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The keywords with the most impact are the one's in the TITLE tag, not the Body. So edit your html file and put `<title> Keyword keyword </title>` in the header.

Remember it takes adsense up to 7 days to adjust